# Gap in plot between forecasted and real data

Tags: time-series, data-visualization, forecasting

I'm trying to plot forecast and real data on the same plot. But there is always gap between them on the image :

[image]

I use for the forecasting following code:
    y=boardings[,1]
    ## Simple Exponential smoothing
    #predict existing values
    results=HoltWinters(y,beta=FALSE, gamma=FALSE)
    #print data
    print(cbind(y,results$fitted))
    #draw the plot with fitted values
    plot(results)
    #predict future values
    results2=forecast.HoltWinters(results,h=12)
    print(results2)

```
#draw the plot with prediction
plot.forecast(results2,lwd=1,xlab='time',ylab='log.boardings',main='12-month prediction by Exponential Smoothing')
```

The data is taken from the [timeSeries](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timeSeries/index.html) package with name `boardings`.

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

The data are in discrete months. The historical data are connected with a line, and the forecasts are connected with a line. So there is no gap, it is just that no line is drawn between the last historical observation and the first forecast.

Comment: Actually there is value for this period (March), but it does not plot it. Seems like it misses only March, the last value in the real data.

Comment: Three values are plotted in 2006, so it looks like March is being plotted to me. But unless you give replicable code, nobody can help further. The timeSeries package does not contain an object called boardings. I think you probably mean the TSA package. When I plot the boardings object from TSA, it is identical to what is plotted in your graph including the March 2006 figure.

Comment: @Rob Hyndman : Is there any any possibility of joining the end of historical data and start of forecasted data with some dotted lines?

Comment: @Ashish. With R you can do whatever you like.

Comment: @RobHyndman : Thanks achieved it with segments() in plot and geom_segment() in ggplot.